# Understanding VMware SRM Failover network settings

Tags: vmware, failover, esxi, vmware-server

[image]

Hi Guys,

We are planning to build fail-over Datacenter.

So you can check the picture for infrastructure

Please help me to figure it out:

Questions:

1. What if OpenVPN-1 fails, but Primary Site is not failing(no physical, not power, everything is fine) just no connection to primary site, How it will connect to recovery site? how Primary site detects that no connection between Primary Site and office so failovers to Recovery site?
2. Do i have to install/Build something in Office which detects no connection to primary site, so it will warns/signals to the Recovery site the come online and put primary site to offline and/or out of service?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `SRM` Disaster Recovery requires manual attention for `Failover`. You need to login in Recovery site `vCenter` using `vSphere` client and trigger `Recovery` under Site Recovery Manager.
2. Yes. You could automate `Failover` by checking connection to primary site, but it would require significant effort.